# Python. Несколько отмеченных радио-кнопок единовременно

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, pyside2

Я назначил каждому пользователю 2 радио-кнопки: `вкл - выкл`, но в данной реализации на всю таблицу может быть отмечена только 1 кнопка.

Другими словами я не могу 2 раза отметить `выкл` у 2-х разных пользователей.

Как мне это сделать?

```
class Main(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def closeEvent(self, event):  # Override standard method

        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Подтвердите действие', "Вы уверены, что хотите выйти",
                                     QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.Yes)  # Last param - focus

        event.accept() if reply == QMessageBox.Yes else event.ignore()

    def center(self):  # Is it working?
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def button_сlick(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print(sender.text() + ' was pressed')
        pass

    def initUI(self):
        self.center()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 280, 280)
        self.setWindowTitle('Таблица пользователей')
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()  # adjust row by content
        # self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))
        self.setColumnCount(len(row_labels))
        self.setRowCount(len(users))
        for y, user in enumerate(users):
            btn_on = QRadioButton('вкл')
            btn_off = QRadioButton('выкл')
            button_group = QButtonGroup()
            button_group.addButton(btn_on)
            button_group.addButton(btn_off)
            btn_on.clicked.connect(self.button_сlick)
            btn_off.clicked.connect(self.button_сlick)
            self.setItem(y, 0, QTableWidgetItem(user['mail']))
            self.setItem(y, 1, QTableWidgetItem(user['online']))
            self.setItem(y, 2, QTableWidgetItem(user['warning']))
            self.setItem(y, 3, QTableWidgetItem(user['usd']))
            self.setItem(y, 4, QTableWidgetItem(user['rub']))
            self.setItem(y, 5, QTableWidgetItem(user['eur']))
            self.setItem(y, 6, QTableWidgetItem(user['full_name']))
            self.setItem(y, 8, self.setCellWidget(y, 8, btn_on))  # can remove setItem
            self.setItem(y, 9, self.setCellWidget(y, 9, btn_off))
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Не более 1 отмеченной кнопки на всю таблицу:(]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick Это он и есть, только данных для таблицы не предоставлено (у меня их сейчас нет, я их получаю по API, оно врменно недоступно. Однако я сомневаюсь, что наличие данных поможет ответить на типовой вопрос, тем более скриншот предоставлен

Comment: А попробуйте так: `button_group.setExclusive(False)`. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#exclusive-prop

Comment: @gil9red Попробовал, не помогло.

Comment: @DavidShiko, а, я неправильно понял как вы button_group используется, мне показалось, что он один на всю таблицу, а тут на каждую ячейку свой, тогда это, действительно, не поможет :) Тогда, нужно все кнопки выкл добавлять в список и при клике на одну из них проверять у нее значение и менять, например, другим, это решение в лоб

Comment: @gil9red пожалуйста, выделите пару минут, проверьте мой ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял ошибку!

[Ссылка на оригинальный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45384800/14395678)

`QButtonGroup()` Должен наследоваться от созданного класса, а не импортируемоего!

1. Замените `button_group = QButtonGroup()` на `button_group = QButtonGroup(self)`
2. Удалите строчку `button_group.setExclusive(False)`

Весь код: (Не все импорты нужны)

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QWidget, QPushButton, QRadioButton, \
    QButtonGroup, QMessageBox, QDesktopWidget, QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox


row_labels = ["Логин", "Статус", "Уведомления", "USD", "EUR", "RUB", "ФИО", "Режим", "ВКЛ", "ВЫКЛ"]
row_tooltips = ["Е-мэйл пользователя. Пример: bessgmail.com",
                "Баланс пользователя. Пример: 29 552,78",
                "Баланс пользователя. Пример: 29 552,78",
                "Баланс пользователя. Пример: 29 552,78",
                "Количесвто уведомлений у пользователя. Пример: 2",
                "Статус пользователя, активен или выключен. Пример: выключено",
                "ФИО пользователя, пример: Веселова Галина Анатольевна",
                "ФИО пользователя, пример: Веселова Галина Анатольевна",
                "Режим, в котором запущен скрипт (с графикой или без). Пример: No_GUI",
                "Режим, в котором запущен скрипт (с графикой или без). Пример: No_GUI"
                ]


users = [{
    'mail': 'users 1',
    'online': 'users 2',
    'warning': 'users 3',
    'usd': 'users 4',
    'rub': 'users 5',
    'eur': 'users 6',
    'full_name': 'users 7'
},
    {'mail': 'users 11', 'online': 'users 21', 'warning': 'users 31', 'usd': 'users 41',
     'rub': 'users 51', 'eur': 'users 61', 'full_name': 'users 71'},
    {'mail': 'users 1', 'online': 'users 2', 'warning': 'users 3', 'usd': 'users 4',
     'rub': 'users 52', 'eur': 'users 6', 'full_name': 'users 72'},
    {'mail': 'users 1', 'online': 'users 2', 'warning': 'users 3', 'usd': 'users 4',
     'rub': 'users 53', 'eur': 'users 6', 'full_name': 'users 73'},
]


class Main(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def closeEvent(self, event):  # Override standard method

        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Подтвердите действие', "Вы уверены, что хотите выйти",
                                     QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.Yes)  # Last param - focus

        event.accept() if reply == QMessageBox.Yes else event.ignore()

    def center(self):  # Is it working?
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def button_сlick(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print(sender.text() + ' was pressed')
        pass
        pass

    def run_user(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print(sender.text() + ' was pressed')


    def initUI(self):
        self.center()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 280, 280)
        self.setWindowTitle('Таблица пользователей')
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()  # adjust row by content
        self.setColumnCount(len(row_labels))
        self.setRowCount(len(users))
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(row_labels)
        for x, row in enumerate(row_labels):
            self.horizontalHeaderItem(x).setToolTip(row_tooltips[x])
        for y, user in enumerate(users):
            btn_on = QRadioButton('вкл')
            btn_off = QRadioButton('выкл')

            button_group = QButtonGroup(self)
            button_group.addButton(btn_on)
            button_group.addButton(btn_off)

            btn_on.clicked.connect(self.run_user)
            btn_off.clicked.connect(self.run_user)
            self.setItem(y, 0, QTableWidgetItem(user['mail']))
            self.setItem(y, 1, QTableWidgetItem(user['online']))
            self.setItem(y, 2, QTableWidgetItem(user['warning']))
            self.setItem(y, 3, QTableWidgetItem(user['usd']))
            self.setItem(y, 4, QTableWidgetItem(user['rub']))
            self.setItem(y, 5, QTableWidgetItem(user['eur']))
            self.setItem(y, 6, QTableWidgetItem(user['full_name']))
            self.setItem(y, 8, self.setCellWidget(y, 8, btn_on))  # can remove setItem
            self.setItem(y, 9, self.setCellWidget(y, 9, btn_off)))
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

То что вы предоставили - не является воспроизводимым примером! Мне пришлось потратить какое-то время, чтобы запустить ваш код и это НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО!

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import * 


class Main(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def closeEvent(self, event):  
        reply = QMessageBox.question(
            self, 
            'Подтвердите действие', 
            "Вы уверены, что хотите выйти",
            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.Yes
        ) 
        event.accept() if reply == QMessageBox.Yes else event.ignore()

    def center(self):  
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def button_сlick(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print(sender.text() + ' was pressed')
        pass

    def initUI(self):
        self.center()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 280, 280)
        self.setWindowTitle('Таблица пользователей')
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()  
        
#??? row_labels  ??? users
        row_labels = ['row_labels 1', 'row_labels 2', 'row_labels 3', 'row_labels 4', ]
        users = [{
            'mail': 'users 1',  
            'online': 'users 2', 
            'warning': 'users 3', 
            'usd': 'users 4',
            'rub': 'users 5', 
            'eur': 'users 6', 
            'full_name': 'users 7'
        },
        {'mail': 'users 11', 'online': 'users 21', 'warning': 'users 31', 'usd': 'users 41',
         'rub': 'users 51', 'eur': 'users 61', 'full_name': 'users 71'},
        {'mail': 'users 1', 'online': 'users 2', 'warning': 'users 3', 'usd': 'users 4',
         'rub': 'users 52', 'eur': 'users 6', 'full_name': 'users 72'},
         {'mail': 'users 1', 'online': 'users 2', 'warning': 'users 3', 'usd': 'users 4',
         'rub': 'users 53', 'eur': 'users 6', 'full_name': 'users 73'},
        ]
        
        self.setColumnCount(10)                   #(len(row_labels)   -> row_labels ???)
        
        
        self.setRowCount(len(users))
        for y, user in enumerate(users):
            btn_on = QRadioButton('вкл')
            btn_off = QRadioButton('выкл')
            
            groupbox_1 = QGroupBox() 
            h1_layout = QHBoxLayout(groupbox_1)
            h1_layout.addWidget(btn_on)
            h1_layout.addWidget(btn_off)
            
            button_group = QButtonGroup(self)   
            button_group.addButton(btn_on)
            button_group.addButton(btn_off)
            button_group.buttonClicked['int'].connect(
                lambda _id, row=y: self.buttonGroupClicked(_id, row)
            )
            
            self.setItem(y, 0, QTableWidgetItem(user['mail']))
            self.setItem(y, 1, QTableWidgetItem(user['online']))
            self.setItem(y, 2, QTableWidgetItem(user['warning']))
            self.setItem(y, 3, QTableWidgetItem(user['usd']))
            self.setItem(y, 4, QTableWidgetItem(user['rub']))
            self.setItem(y, 5, QTableWidgetItem(user['eur']))
            self.setItem(y, 6, QTableWidgetItem(user['full_name']))
            
#            self.setItem(y, 8, self.setCellWidget(y, 8, btn_on))  # can remove setItem
#            self.setItem(y, 9, self.setCellWidget(y, 9, btn_off))
            
            self.setItem(y, 8, self.setCellWidget(y, 8, groupbox_1))
            self.setRowHeight(y, 40)
            self.setColumnWidth(8, 150)
        
    def buttonGroupClicked(self, _id, row):
        print(f'{self.sender().button(_id).text()} в строке {row}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Main()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прошу прощения, учту в будущем. Ваш код кстати тоже не работает как на скрине

Comment: @DavidShiko на каком скрине мой пример не работает? Вы пробовали запустить мой пример?

Comment: @gil9red не мог понять, где написано, что  для одного юзера может быть несколько строк? В вопросе написано: назначил каждому пользователю 2 радио-кнопки: вкл - выкл, но в данной реализации на всю таблицу может быть отмечена только 1 кнопка. Другими словами я не могу 2 раза отметить выкл `у 2-х разных пользователей`.

Comment: @DavidShiko, вопрос возник насчет поведения радио-кнопок. Объясните подробнее, что должно происходит с кнопками при их клике. Кнопки между строками зависят друг от друга, т.е. при смене состояния у кнопок в одной строке, меняются и в других строках?

Comment: @S.Nick Да, у вас радио кнопок нет [скриншот](https://ibb.co/BsWZFvB)

Comment: @DavidShiko изъясняйтесь пожалуйста яснее, каких радио кнопок у меня нет? Вы получаете результат, который я привел на изображении? или что вы получаете?

Comment: @gil9red Нет, абсолютно не зависят. По нажатию кнопки я создаю экземпляр класса (запускаю скрипт для пользователя). Т.е. здесь банальное управление: запустить скрипт для пользователя, завершить скрипт для пользователя. 2х одинаковых пользователей быть не должно (надеюсь АПИ, где я их получаю, меня не подведет) ))

Comment: @S.Nick Я получаю именно то, что опубликовал на скриншоте. Вывод в консоле есть, но самих кнопок не видно. Подозреваю, что какой то "слой" их (радиокнопки) перекрыл.

Comment: @DavidShiko опубликуйте пожалуйста именно тот пример, о котором вы только что написали, т.е. в котором не видно кнопок.

Comment: @S.Nick Это ваш код, вся речь сейчас о вашем коде. Я запускаю ваш код и в нем нет кнопок (скриншот тоже вашего кода). Опубликовать ваш код?
На вашем скриншоте я вижу кнопки и это странно, возможно, дело в операционной системе. У вас windows, у меня linux, т.е. теоретически они могут отображать по разному элементы, но я бы счел это скорее багом. Я попробую сэмулировать виндовс среду у себя, но не уверен, что получится.

Еще момент: в вашем коде на первый взгляд не используется объект `h1_layout`, так и надо?

Comment: @DavidShiko  теперь стало понятно. Поменяйте строк `self.setRowHeight(y, 60)`, т..е.  установите `60` вместо `СОРОКА`.

Comment: @S.Nick К сожалению не помогло [скриншот с новым размером](https://ibb.co/82fRQ3d). Вы обратили внимание про неиспользуемый `h1_layout` ?

Comment: @DavidShiko добавьте строку `app.setStyle("Fusion")` после строки  `app = QApplication(sys.argv)`. И попробуйте, если не увидите, увеличить высоту строки вручную (т.е. растянуть строку).

Comment: @S.Nick. Я опубликовал ответ, спасибо большое за помощь. В вашем примере скорее всего проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь положить `groupbox_1` в таблицу, которое не имеет графического представления (нужно класть сами кнопки). Кстати, `h1_layout` можно так-же удалить

Comment: @S.Nick Можешь пожалуйста прокомментировать эту строчку ` button_group.buttonClicked['int']`, чем она отличается от `btn_on.clicked.connect` ?

Comment: @DavidShiko если у вас есть трудности с использованием сигналов, задайте новый вопрос. Опишите проблемную ситуацию, приведите минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему и вам сообщество поможет,  так думаю.